# How do I get the CSRF token in Yii without setting the _csrf cookie?

Tags: php, cookies, yii2

How do I get the CSRF token in Yii without setting the `_csrf` token? I tried many things, but nothing works. Each time I try to access the CSRF token, it sets a cookie.

```
  <?//= Html::csrfMetaTags() // sets _csrf cookie. prevents Fastly CDN caching. ?>
  <?php 
    $this->registerMetaTag(['name' => 'csrf-param', 'content' => '_csrf']);
    $this->registerMetaTag(['name' => 'csrf-token', 'content' => 'xxx']);
    Yii::$app->request->csrfToken;
  ?>
```

Yields

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:81/xxx/web/shopping/search?q=toaster
...
Set-Cookie: _csrf=0fe1db8822f87506dd00feefb32438ffee24116b4ec717287e23422d81feb32ea%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22DkE4S5EYilTEkubAr-dWda5CV0y5XCEp%22%3B%7D; path=/; httponly
```

It doesn't set the cookie when I comment out `Yii::$app->request->csrfToken;`. I've also tried unsetting the cookie immediately afterward, but it sends `Set-Cookie: _csrf=delete; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;` to the browser then. I also tried setting [`$enableCsrfCookie`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#$enableCsrfCookie-detail) to false, but then it sets `PHPSESSID` cookie.

I need the CSRF meta tags for the logout link, which uses POST and Javascript to submit. The forms work OK as they insert the CSRF into the `<form>` tags.

Comment: I've discovered that the other forms DO NOT work OK without the `_csrf` cookie. I just had an old `PHPSESSID` and `_csrf` cookie in my browser. If you delete those cookies from your browser, then it gives a `Bad Request (#400)` error. So you have to find a way to keep the cookie or session on the pages you want.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that there is a second parameter to [`remove()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-cookiecollection.html#remove()-detail) which prevents sending to the browser, so I can get the token, then immediately delete the cookie.

```
Yii::$app->response->cookies->remove('_csrf', false);
```